# Generate strings in lexicographical order in Python

Tags: python, generator, lazy-sequences, lexicographic

How can I write a Python generator that lazily generates all strings composed of lowercase English letters of up to a certain length<sup>1</sup>?

I have written my own solution ([posted below as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64647186/6117426)), but I would like to see if there are any more elegant/efficient/fun solutions out there.

---

<sup>1</sup> An infinite iterator would be pretty useless because it would just generate strings composed of only the character `a`. This is because the lexicographical ordering of strings is not a [well-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order); it can be thought of as composed of an infinite sequence of infinitely nested sequences: (`a`, (`aa`, ...), (`ab`, ...), ...), (`b`, (`ba`, ...), (`bb`, ...), ...), ... The generator would never reach `ab` since it has an infinite amount of predecessors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```py
import string


def lexstrings(max_length: int, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    yield ""
    if max_length == 0: return
    for first in alphabet:
        for suffix in lexstrings(max_length - 1, alphabet=alphabet):
            yield first + suffix
```

Example:

```
>>> g = lexstrings(max_length=3, alphabet="ab")
>>> list(g)
['',
 'a',
 'aa',
 'aaa',
 'aab',
 'ab',
 'aba',
 'abb',
 'b',
 'ba',
 'baa',
 'bab',
 'bb',
 'bba',
 'bbb']
```

This might not be the best solution because it involves recursion and using the `+` operator `m` times to generate a string of length `m`, which isn't efficient because Python generates copies of the intermediate results (since strings are immutable).

This implementation also "supports" the infinite version:

```
>>> g = lexstrings(-1)
>>> next(g)
''
>>> next(g)
'a'
>>> next(g)
'aa'
>>> next(g)
'aaa'
...
```